# jquery setinterval minimize queue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, setinterval

I am using jQuery to animate a banner, using fadein, fadeout and append.  The problem I am having, is that while the desired outcome has been generated, every time I minimize or change tabs, the animations queue and then the webpage goes crazy when I open it again!

How can I prevent this from happening?  Could I add an if statement to check if the animation is already running?  Can I bottle neck it to one animation?

Consider:

```
$(function () {
    var fElement = $('.fadein');
    fElement.find('img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!fElement.data('paused')) {
            fElement.find(':first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
        } else {
             console.log('waiting...');
        }
    }, 5000);

    $('map').hover(
        function() {
            console.log('pausing');
            fElement.data('paused', 1);
        },
        function() {
            console.log('unpausing');
            fElement.data('paused', 0);
        }
    );
});

        if ( !console && !console.log ){
            console = {};
        console.log = function(){};
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="#" usemap="#" border="0" width="964" height="49" alt="" style="" id="level2Menu"/>
    <img src="#" usemap="#" border="0" width="964" height="49" alt="" style="" id="level2Menu"/>
</div>
```

Also, a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8ztR/

Although it seems to be behaving strangely...

Thanks!

EDIT: FIXED USING .stop(true,true)!

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your setInterval Call by that

```
 var continueLooping = true;
(function theLoop (){
  if (!fElement.data('paused')) {
            fElement.find(':first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    } else {
         console.log('waiting...');
    }
  if(continueLooping){
   setTimeout(theLoop, 5000);
   }
})();
```

What that does is exactly like setInterval except that the code actually waits to be executed before launching the next Timeout iteration.
more explanations on the amazing:
http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

you can then instead of setting the data paused or not
setting continueLooping to true or false, or call this code multiple times (don't do it)

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I think I have a syntax error now & can't seem to spot what it is, firebug isn't being very helpful either...

I'll edit the OP